# Python build error while building selenium webdriver project

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, compiler-errors, rake, open-source

I'm attempting to get into some opensource projects, and as a QA engineer, have been looking at Appium and Selenium.

- Situation: Windows 10
- Appium: cloned repo, built successfully
- Selenium: cloned, but having troubles.
- Installed: Java, JDK, python 3.6, Ruby, Rake gem.
- Error, I use go + a target, eg 'go build', 'go' or 'go firefox'. However I'm always getting the following error:

The error:

```
C:\Users\Mark\selenium>go build
(in C:/Users/Mark/selenium)
python C:/Users/Mark/selenium/buck-out/crazy-fun/7c1417f319649e9fd58fd3f97f36f42c870b1790/buck.pex kill
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\selenium\buck-out\crazy-fun\7c1417f319649e9fd58fd3f97f36f42c870b1790\buck.pex\__main__.py", line 25, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mark\selenium\buck-out\crazy-fun\7c1417f319649e9fd58fd3f97f36f42c870b1790\buck.pex\.bootstrap\_pex\pex_bootstrapper.py", line 94, in bootstrap_pex
  File "C:\Users\Mark\selenium\buck-out\crazy-fun\7c1417f319649e9fd58fd3f97f36f42c870b1790\buck.pex\.bootstrap\_pex\finders.py", line 218, in register_finders
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'FileFinder'
go aborted!
```

I'm unable to find anything similar online aside from one post suggesting an issue with older versions of Python potentially. However I've just downloaded the latest, so wouldn't expect an issue...

Comment: The Selenium build script uses Buck, which requires the use of Python 2.x. It is incompatible with Python 3. This is a limitation of the build tool, not the Selenium project itself.

Comment: @JimEvans thanks, the Selenium slack channel suggested I try downgrading, and yep. However that just got me to the next issue with buck ;)

Comment: @JimEvans came back to this today, got further, but I'm still stuck (I feel so close!).  If you have a chance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56981193/compiling-selenium-buck-issues

Answer (score 0):

The Selenium build scripts utilised here (either crazyfunbuild or buckd depending on setup and tools installed) uses Python 2.7 (at time of writing).

A downgrade from 3.6 to 2.7 solved my (python) issues at least.