# Compiling project with buck, claims I have no jdk

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, compiler-errors, java-8, buck

I'm still trying to get the selenium open source project to build.

[As per my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45657453/175051), downgrading python to 2.7 fixed an initial issue.

However, I'm now consistently (tried on two machines) getting an error about the jdk:

```
C:\Users\Mark\selenium>go.bat
(in C:/Users/Mark/selenium)
python C:/Users/Mark/selenium/buck-out/crazy-fun/7c1417f319649e9fd58fd3f97f36f42c870b1790/buck.pex kill
Build ID: 22661051-9fce-45f4-96b2-1fd0e2fbadcd
[-] PARSING BUCK FILES...FINISHED 18.8s [100%]
BUILD FAILED: //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/testing/drivers:browser failed:
javac -source 8 -target 8 -sourcepath  -g -proc:none -d C:\Users\Mark\selenium\buck-out\bin\java\client\test\org\openqa\selenium\testing\drivers\lib__browser__classes -classpath '' @buck-out\gen\java\client\test\org\openqa\selenium\testing\drivers\__browser__srcs
No system compiler found. Did you install the JRE instead of the JDK?
[-] BUILDING...FINISHED 6.3s [100%] (35/333 JOBS, 4 UPDATED, 4 [1.2%] CACHE MISS)
[-] DOWNLOADING... (0.00 B/S AVG, TOTAL: 0.00 B, 0 Artifacts)
go aborted!
Buck build failed with exit code: 1
```

However, I definitely have java and javac on the path:

```
C:\Users\Mark\selenium>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_144

C:\Users\Mark\selenium>java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

I've also checked %JAVA_HOME%:

```
C:\Users\Mark\selenium>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

I've searched and searched but while a couple of people online have had similar issues on other projects while using buck, nobody has a solution that has sorted my issue.

Answers welcomed, theories welcomed as comments too!

Comment: check the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`  is whether set correctly?

Comment: @holi-java yes, thanks, I've got that. Added to question.

Comment: well, you can try to set the `PATH` environment as `SET PATH = %JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%` to make sure the `java` command is executed in `bin` rather than `jre/bin`. since the `go.bat` execute `java` command directly.

Comment: @holi-java that's it! If you can add that as an answer, you just solved my hours of problems :) Thanks

Comment: Not at all. I'm not good at english. maybe you need to add an answer by yourself, :). I'll upvote yours.

Comment: @holi-java please add that as an answer so that it could be helpful for others