# Compiling selenium webdriver source - buck issues

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, compiler-errors, rake, buck

Been spending yesterday compiling the open source Appium tool, and today Selenium.

Between the projects, on Windows, I've had to install different versions of the JDK, ruby, python 2.7 (I had 3.6), git, ffmpeg, opencv4nodejs,nodejs, npm, choco and a variety of other random tools and utilities. cmake.  Bundletool. Ant.

Anyway, I've gotten further than I've gotten before, but now for the last few hours I'm stuck.

`go.bat clean` executes fine
`go.bat <anything else>` seems to fail, whether its used with `test_java`, `test_htmlunit`, `build`, `test_firefox` and more.

However, I've not been able to track down where in the miles of rake/buck stuff the actual error is coming from.

An example:

```
go.bat test_java
```

Output:

$ ./go.bat test_java

> C:\Users\mayom\selenium>java -Xmx4096m -XX:MetaspaceSize=1024m
>   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -client -jar third_party/jruby/jruby-complete.jar -X-C -S rake test_java python
>   buckw kill python buckw build --stamp-build=detect --deep
>   //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test Starting new Buck
>   daemon... PARSING BUCK FILES: FINISHED IN 1.7s CREATING ACTION GRAPH:
>   FINISHED IN 0.4s BUILT 145/223 JOBS 1.2s //javascript/webdriver:key
>   BUILT 146/223 JOBS 4.1s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote:remote-gen-manifest BUILT
>   147/223 JOBS 4.8s //third_party/java/jetty:jetty-gen-manifest BUILT
>   148/223 JOBS 4.5s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium:core-gen-manifest BUILT 149/223
>   JOBS 1.9s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote:remote-lib-build-info
>   BUILT 150/223 JOBS 1.3s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium:core-lib-build-info BUILT
>   151/223 JOBS 2.7s //third_party/java/jetty:jetty-lib-build-info BUILT
>   181/223 JOBS 1.3s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote:remote-lib-build-info#class-abi
>   BUILT 185/223 JOBS 1.3s
>   //third_party/java/jetty:jetty-lib-build-info#class-abi BUILT 189/223
>   JOBS 0.2s //javascript/atoms:events BUILT 197/223 JOBS 0.8s
>   //javascript/atoms:inject BUILT 198/223 JOBS 1.4s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium:core-lib-build-info#class-abi
>   BUILT 199/223 JOBS 0.8s //javascript/atoms:locators BUILT 200/223 JOBS
>   0.9s //javascript/atoms:html5 BUILT 201/223 JOBS 0.5s //javascript/atoms:devices BUILT 206/223 JOBS 0.4s
>   //javascript/atoms:action BUILT 207/223 JOBS 0.2s
>   //javascript/webdriver/atoms:atoms-lib STILL BUILDING
>   //third_party/java/jetty:move-services (20 seconds) STILL BUILDING
>   //javascript/atoms/fragments:execute_script (20 seconds) STILL
>   BUILDING //javascript/webdriver/atoms:inputs (20 seconds)
>
> C:\Users\mayom\selenium\buck-out\gen\third_party\java\jetty\move-services__srcs>md
>   tmp   && cd tmp   && jar xf
>   C:\Users\mayom\selenium\buck-out\gen\third_party\java\jetty\bundle-jars.jar
>   && del META-INF/services/*   && echo
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder
>   1>META-INF\services\org.seleniumhq.jetty9.http.HttpFieldPreEncoder  &&
>   jar cvf
>   C:\Users\mayom\selenium\buck-out\gen\third_party\java\jetty\move-services\moved-bundle.jar
>   *
>
> Parameter format not correct - "services".
>
> STILL BUILDING //javascript/atoms/fragments:execute_script (40
>   seconds) STILL BUILDING //javascript/webdriver/atoms:inputs (40
>   seconds) BUILT 209/223 JOBS 45.2s
>   //javascript/atoms/fragments:execute_script BUILT 210/223 JOBS 50.8s
>   //javascript/webdriver/atoms:inputs DOWNLOADED 0 ARTIFACTS, 0.00
>   BYTES, 100.0% CACHE MISS BUILDING: FINISHED IN 1m 2.4s (100%) 210/223
>   JOBS, 20 UPDATED BUILD FAILED Command failed with exit code 1. stderr:
>   Parameter format not correct - "services".
>
> ```
> When running <genrule>.
> When building rule //third_party/java/jetty:move-services. go aborted! python buckw build --stamp-build=detect --deep
> ```
>
> //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test failed with exit
>   code: 1 C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:52:in `block in
>   buck_cmd' C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:36:in`buck_cmd'
>   C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:227:in `block in (root)'
>   Tasks: TOP => test_java =>
>   //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test:run =>
>   //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test (See full trace by
>   running task with --trace)

And if I run it with --trace:

> $ ./go.bat test_java --trace
>
> C:\Users\mayom\selenium>java -Xmx4096m -XX:MetaspaceSize=1024m
>   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -client -jar third_party/jruby/jruby-complete.jar -X-C -S rake test_java --trace
>   Parsing cpp/build.desc Parsing cpp/iedriverserver/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/build.desc Parsing javascript/android-atoms/build.desc
>   Parsing javascript/atoms/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/atoms/fragments/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/chrome-driver/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/ie-driver/build.desc Parsing javascript/jsunit/build.desc
>   Parsing javascript/node/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/remote/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/selenium-atoms/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/selenium-core/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/webdriver/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/webdriver/atoms/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/webdriver/atoms/fragments/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/webdriver/atoms/fragments/inject/build.desc Parsing
>   javascript/webdriver/atoms/inject/build.desc Parsing py/build.desc
>   Parsing rb/build.desc Parsing third_party/closure/build.desc Parsing
>   third_party/firebug/build.desc Parsing third_party/jruby/build.desc
>   Parsing third_party/js/sizzle/build.desc Parsing
>   third_party/js/wgxpath/build.desc
>   ** Invoke test_java (first_time)
>   ** Invoke //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test:run (first_time)
>   ** Invoke //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test (first_time)
>   ** Execute //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test python buckw kill python buckw build --stamp-build=detect --deep
>   //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test Starting new Buck
>   daemon... PARSING BUCK FILES: FINISHED IN 1.7s CREATING ACTION GRAPH:
>   FINISHED IN 0.5s BUILT 146/223 JOBS 3.9s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote:remote-gen-manifest BUILT
>   147/223 JOBS 4.2s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium:core-gen-manifest BUILT 148/223
>   JOBS 4.4s //third_party/java/jetty:jetty-gen-manifest BUILT 155/223
>   JOBS 0.8s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium:core-lib-build-info#class-abi
>   BUILT 179/223 JOBS 2.5s //third_party/java/jetty:jetty-lib-build-info
>   BUILT 187/223 JOBS 2.8s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote:remote-lib-build-info
>   BUILT 189/223 JOBS 0.8s
>   //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:execute_script BUILT
>   191/223 JOBS 1.4s
>   //third_party/java/jetty:jetty-lib-build-info#class-abi BUILT 195/223
>   JOBS 2.7s //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium:core-lib-build-info
>   BUILT 206/223 JOBS 0.7s
>   //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:atoms_inputs BUILT
>   207/223 JOBS 1.2s
>   //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote:remote-lib-build-info#class-abi
>
> C:\Users\mayom\selenium\buck-out\gen\third_party\java\jetty\move-services__srcs>md
>   tmp   && cd tmp   && jar xf
>   C:\Users\mayom\selenium\buck-out\gen\third_party\java\jetty\bundle-jars.jar
>   && del META-INF/services/*   && echo
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.http.Http1FieldPreEncoder
>   1>META-INF\services\org.seleniumhq.jetty9.http.HttpFieldPreEncoder  &&
>   jar cvf
>   C:\Users\mayom\selenium\buck-out\gen\third_party\java\jetty\move-services\moved-bundle.jar
>   *
>
> Parameter format not correct - "services".
>
> DOWNLOADED 0 ARTIFACTS, 0.00 BYTES, 100.0% CACHE MISS BUILDING:
>   FINISHED IN 14.2s (100%) 212/223 JOBS, 12 UPDATED BUILD FAILED Command
>   failed with exit code 1. stderr: Parameter format not correct -
>   "services".
>
> ```
> When running <genrule>.
> When building rule //third_party/java/jetty:move-services. Exception `RuntimeError' at
> ```
>
> C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:52 - python buckw build
>   --stamp-build=detect --deep //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test failed with exit
>   code: 1 Exception `#<Class:#<RuntimeError:0x1ee40b5c>>' at
>   C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:52 - python buckw build
>   --stamp-build=detect --deep //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test failed with exit
>   code: 1 Exception`#>' at
>   C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:52 - python buckw build
>   --stamp-build=detect --deep //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test failed with exit
>   code: 1 Exception `#<Class:#<RuntimeError:0x1ee40b5c>>' at
>   C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:52 - python buckw build
>   --stamp-build=detect --deep //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test failed with exit
>   code: 1 go aborted! python buckw build --stamp-build=detect --deep
>   //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test failed with exit
>   code: 1 C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:52:in`block in
>   buck_cmd' org/jruby/RubyIO.java:4902:in `popen3'
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/jruby/open3_windows.rb:74:in`
>   popen3' C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:36:in `buck_cmd'
>   C:/Users/mayom/selenium/rake-tasks/buck.rb:227:in`block in (root)'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in
>   execute' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in`each'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in`block in
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/monitor.rb:214:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in
>   invoke_prerequisites' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in`each'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in
>   `invoke_prerequisites'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in`block in
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/monitor.rb:214:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in
>   invoke_prerequisites' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in`each'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in
>   `invoke_prerequisites'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in`block in
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/monitor.rb:214:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level' org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1735:in`each'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in
>   `block in top_level'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`
>   run_with_threads'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in
>   `top_level'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`block
>   in run'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`run'
>   uri:classloader:/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
>   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:973:in`load'
>   uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/bin/rake:1:in `' Tasks: TOP
>   => test_java => //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test:run => //java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/atoms:test

The parameter 'services'? I can't find for the life of me where that complaint is coming from.  Would appreciate anyone with a more indepth knowledge of rake/buck etc than myself.